# Javadoc/ API documentation and code co-evolution: Existing work, tools?

Tags: java, javadoc, api-design

Is there existing tool support for the following scenarios based on Javadoc and Javadoc's infrastructure (e.g.: Doclet API):

- Doc/API consistency checking: e.g. documented methods or method params went missing from the implemented API or vice versa?
- Coupled evolution of (round-tripping between) Javadoc comments and the documented Java API (ping-pong between spec-first & code-first kind of evolution)

The only thingies I am aware of are checkstyle's Javadoc checks (but this is not what I am looking for, i am interested in checks between documented code and comments, not style checks on comments itselves).

Any hints or pointers would be much appreciated!

Stefan